# No handler found for path in Helidon

Tags: microservices, jax-rs, helidon

I have created a simple endpoint in Helidon:

```
@GET
@Path("/sampleString")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Message getSampleString() {
    return "{'Sample':'String'}";
}
```

The code complies and runs. But when I call:

`curl -i http://localhost:8080/sampleString`

I receive:

```
No handler found for path: /sampleString
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you are missing the `META-INF/beans.xml` file.

It should be as simple as that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                           https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

To check it you may set `org.jboss.level=DEBUG` in `logging.properties`. When you run your app, you should see something like:

```
 WARNING io.helidon.microprofile.server.ServerCdiExtension Thread[#1,main,5,main]: There are no JAX-RS applications or resources. Maybe you forgot META-INF/beans.xml file?
```

Comment: I added the above change.But still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

for CDI to discover and manage you bean, your class has to have a  scope (e.g. Request, Session, etc. )

dose you bean have scope like @RequestScoped if not add it to your class
e.g.

```
@RequestScoped
pulic class YourResource {

  @GET
  @Path("/sampleString")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Message getSampleString() {
      return "{'Sample':'String'}";
  }

...

}
```